# Adding tool tips to dojo DataGrid items

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I would like to add a tooltip with some extra data to each row in a `dojox.grid.DataGrid`. I have tried to create an `onCellMouseOver`-handler, but I can't get the data item data out of the event object I'm getting.

What is the best way to add a tooltip to a `DataGrid`-row?

Answer (score 2):

In your `onCellMouseOver` you can get the row index (`e.rowIndex`). From that you can get the `item` from the `grid` assuming you are using an `ItemFileReadStore` (I have not tried it with a `ItemFileWriteStore`)

```
function cellMouseOver (e)
{
     var rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
     var item = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex);
}
```